# Accessing a method from a Parent class from child1 and child2

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I am learning methods, inheritance and I am also trying to learn how can I call a method from different class. I am trying to access the "Order" method from Parent but I am stuck in this problem because my error is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c1". How can I fix this problem?

```java
class Parent {
    Child1 c1 = new Child1();
    public static int Americano = c1.Americano; // error
    static int CaffeLatte = c1.CaffeLatte;
    static int Cappuccino = c1.Cappuccino;

    static void order() {
        // some statements about choosing which coffee
    }

    class Child1 extends Parent {
        int Americano = 100;
        int CaffeLatte = 125;
        int Cappuccino = 150;
        public Child1() {}
    }

    class Child2 extends Child1 {
        public Child2() {
            Parent.order(); // Here is what I am trying to do.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is, that you access a non static instance `c1` of class `Child1` from the context of a static variable 'Americano'.

To solve this you could just make c1 static.